# How to aggregate sum of all data in django restframe work and it should filter by date

Tags: django, python-3.x, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to filter data by daterange and i am able to do this but i have question how to create  summary of table and  filter by  date also  i am also attached code that you can see and help me out

Actual api look like this

```
 {
        "count": 4,
        "next": null,
        "previous": null,
        "results": [
            {
                "pk": 1,
                "bikeid": "425432",
                "milage": 12,
                "movingtime": "5hr 12min",
                "averagespeed": 14,
                "kgtrasported": 234,
                "co2": 180,
                "additionalbox": 4,
                "nouser": 8,
                "too": "2019-09-23",
                "fromm": "2019-09-23"
            },
            {
                "pk": 2,
                "bikeid": "425433",
                "milage": 11,
                "movingtime": "5hr 12min",
                "averagespeed": 13,
                "kgtrasported": 134,
                "co2": 170,
                "additionalbox": 7,
                "nouser": 4,
                "too": "2019-09-23",
                "fromm": "2019-09-23"
            },
```

But i want that my data will be look like this and it will filter by date also all sum value

```
{
    "count": 4,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "total_milage":23,
    "total_co2":350,
    "total_additionbox":4,
    "total_user":12
    "results": [
        {
            "pk": 1,
            "bikeid": "425432",
            "milage": 12,
            "movingtime": "5hr 12min",
            "averagespeed": 14,
            "kgtrasported": 234,
            "co2": 180,
            "additionalbox": 4,
            "nouser": 8,
            "too": "2019-09-23",
            "fromm": "2019-09-23"
        },
        {
            "pk": 2,
            "bikeid": "425433",
            "milage": 11,
            "movingtime": "5hr 12min",
            "averagespeed": 13,
            "kgtrasported": 134,
            "co2": 170,
            "additionalbox": 7,
            "nouser": 4,
            "too": "2019-09-23",
            "fromm": "2019-09-23"
        },
```

Here is `Views.py`

```
# Electric Bike Add 
class Ebike(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ElectricBike.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ElectricSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = {
        'too': ['lte','gte'],
        'fromm':['lte','gte'],
    }
```

here is `serializers.py`

```
class ElectricSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ElectricBike
        fields = ('pk','bikeid','milage','movingtime','averagespeed','kgtrasported','co2','additionalbox','nouser','too','fromm')
```

[here is screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isNVo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right for that you will have to write the custom pagination class.

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import ElectricBike

class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
                'count': self.page.paginator.count,
                'results': data,
                "total_milage": ElectricBike.objects.annotate(mileage=Sum('mileage')).values_list('mileage', flat=True),
                "total_co2"://your logic here,
                "total_additionbox"://your logic here,
                "total_user"://your logic here

            })
```

and then in your view just mention your Custom Pagination class

```
class Ebike(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ElectricBike.objects.all()
    pagination_class = CustomePagination
    serializer_class = ElectricSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = {
        'too': ['lte','gte'],
        'fromm':['lte','gte'],
    }
```

Comment: Why `Electricbike` Showing Error @HabibUllah Khan

Comment: I would be nice if you can show me the error, @RahulRaj

Comment: "name 'Electricbike' is not defined" This is the error message  and this is code     `'total_milage': Electricbike.objects.annotate(mileage=Sum('mileage')).values_list('mileage', flat=True),`

Comment: Yeah thats because Electricbike model has not been imported, you should import it in your file, I have edited my answer, by the way you can write your own logic to calculate total_mileage